# Why does my turtle object give an error with the setx(x) function?

Tags: python

I'm making a space invaders game, trying to get more comfortable with Python. So I started with the player movement. In my main class I first create the player. After that I try to call the movement methods. But for some reason it looks like I can't call any `turtle` statements with the player object. Why has it lost it's `turtle` attribute?

It's for my space invader game. I tried multiple statements from the turtle library. But none of them seem to work. I tried `goto`, `setx(x)`, `setposition`.

```
import turtle

class Player:
    movementSpeed = 0
    xcor = 0
    ycor = 0

    def __init__(self, movementSpeed, xcor, ycor):
        self.movementSpeed = movementSpeed
        self.xcor = xcor
        self.ycor = ycor
        self = turtle.Turtle()
        self.color("blue")
        self.shape("triangle")
        self.penup()
        self.speed(0)
        self.setposition(xcor, ycor)
        self.setheading(90)

    def move_left(self):
        x = self.xcor
        x -= self.movementSpeed
        if x <  -280:
            x = -280
        self.setx(x)

    def move_right(self):
        x = self.xcor
        x += self.movementSpeed
        if x > 280:
            x = 280
        self.turtle.setx(x)
```

---

```
from Player import Player

player = Player(movementSpeed, 0 ,-250)
wn.onkey(speler.move_left, "Left")
wn.onkey(speler.move_right, "Right")
```

I expected that the player object to move. 
But the following error showed up

```
AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'turtle'
```

Comment: Why would you *expect* it to have a `turtle` attribute?

Comment: I'm new to Python, but I expected it to have it because of the line: self = turtle.Turtle()

Comment: you did not defined `turtle` attribute in constructor, maybe `self.turtle =  turtle.Turtle()`

Comment: Why would `self = turtle.Turtle()` create a `self.turtle` attribute? Doesn't make much sense, does it?

Comment: Thanks! That was it. The problem is solved!

Comment: @Aran-Fey If you spell it out like that it indeed wouldn't make much sense. I understand that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Basic solution

In the `__init__` you assign turtle object to `self` instead of assigning to `self.turtle` so there's no surprise it does not have such attribute.

If you want it to have it, change the mentioned line in the constructor to:

```
self.turtle = turtle.Turtle()
```

### More detailed solution

You are mixing two different approaches: `Player` being a `Turtle` and `Player` consisting of a `Turtle`. If you want the first one, use inheritance:

```
class Player(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Player, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # the rest of the initialization
```

and then use all methods and attributes of Turtle as their are Player's, like:

```
self.shape("triangle")
```

In the case of `Player` consisting of/containg a `Turtle` just use basic solution and in the constructor setup Player's turtle properly:

```
self.turtle = turtle.Turtle()
self.turtle.color("blue")
self.turtle.shape("triangle")
self.turtle.penup()
```